# How to create a workbook named after data in the first workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create an Excel workbook named after the data in the first workbook, so that it has the name of the value contained in column G.

Here is the subroutine:

```vb
Sub Macro1()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        '.Activate
        .Workbooks.Add
        .Range("A1").Value = "=RAND("
        .ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "L:\My Documents\ExcelTestDocument"
        .ActiveWorkbook.Close
        .Quit
    End With

End Sub
```

It saves as ExcelTestDocument.

I want to save as in this subroutine which creates .pdf:

```vb
 Sub createfile()
    'Declare worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    ' declare location to save file as string
    Dim sStoreFile As String
    sStoreFile = "L:\My Documents\ExcelTestDocument"
    
    ' declare filename variable as string
    Dim sFilename As String
    ' declare number of files to create
    Dim iFileCount As Integer
    iFileCount = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row - 1
    
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To iFileCount
        
        ' set the value of the file from spreadsheet
        sFilename = ws.Range("g" & i + 1).Value
        
        ' If extension has "pdf" then save as PDF
        If Right(sFilename, 3) = "pdf" Then
            ws.Range("A" & iFileCount + 5).Clear
            ws.Range("A" & iFileCount + 5).Value = sFilename
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sStoreFile & "\" & ws.Range("g" & i + 1).Value
            ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlType
        End If
        
    Next i
    
    MsgBox "All files have been completed"
    
End Sub
```

I tried is to write the code as this:

```
.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "=sStoreFile & "\" & ws.Range("g" & i + 1).Value"
```

I want the new Excel workbook to be created with the name of column G from the current workbook.

What I forgot to mention is that I want the data from all the rows in column G which have the rows in column F with the extension .xlsx:

Here is a picture.
[image]

Comment: Which row in G do you want to use to save your single workbook? G1? The PDF code uses multiple rows in G.

Comment: Sorry, I ommitted a few details, let me update the description. I basically want each row in G that also in row F named "extension", has the extension .xlsx. I will update with screenshot so you know what I mean